# initializing char** with an array of strings

Tags: c, double-pointer

This is regarding single-char pointers and double-char pointers. Here I am trying to initialize a double-pointer with an array of strings while defining the new pointer.

I have tried

```
char arry[] = "Hello World"
char* cptr = "Hello World"
```

It works fine and the difference is the second line is only read-only.  In the same way, I am trying to use double pointers

```
char *darry[] = {"Hello", "World", "C", "Ubuntu"}; 
char **da = {"Hello", "World", "C", "Ubuntu"};
```

I thought the double pointer(da) would work the same as the single pointer but it is giving me an error. Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: ```char *array[]``` declares an array of pointers to ```char```.  ```char  **da``` is a pointer to pointer to ```char```. There's a difference.

Comment: Tip: Use a `NULL` terminator in lists like this, as in `char* x[] = { "a", "b", ..., NULL }` This way if you pass it in to a function where your array decays into a pointer you can still find the end.

Answer (score 0):

`char *darry[]` is an array.

`{"Hello", "World", "C", "Ubuntu"}` is a valid initializer for an *array* of `char *`.

`char **da` is a pointer.

`char **da = {"Hello", "World", "C", "Ubuntu"};` fails as `{"Hello", "World", "C", "Ubuntu"}` is not a valid initializer for a pointer.

To initialize a non-`char *` pointer to the first element of an array, form the array of `char *` with a *compound literal*.  The *array* is then converted to the address of its first element as part of the initialization - which is a `char **`.

```
//          v-----------------------------------------v Array of char *.
char **da = (char *[]){"Hello", "World", "C", "Ubuntu"};
```